# Android cross disolve animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, cross-fade

I wanna make cross disolve animation between two or three gradient in android, like instagram background animation, but i didn't find any libraries, so how to write animation like this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to [this website](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2757) and download the repository from here and all the explanation to use it is also provided.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is exactly what you are looking for.

[InstagramLikeColorTransitionAndroid](https://github.com/Taishi-Y/InstagramLikeColorTransitionAndroid)